# "that like" vs "like that"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I'm studying English.

Today I've learned how to ask a question *"What was that like?"*, and also I've learned a phrase "I like that."

So what is the difference between the word order in *that like* and *like that*?

*"What was like that?"* is this a correct sentence too?

So, probably the answer to *"What was that like?"* would be *"that was amazing."*
And thus, *"Yes, I do like that"* would be an answer to a question  *"Do you like that?"*

If my guess is right, **that** in *"what was **that** like?"* refers to some **specific situation**, while **that** in *"Do you like **that**?"*  refers to some **things** or **activities** (i.e. apples or swimming).

Am I right?
It's chaos to me. T-T

Answer (score 3):

They are two different meanings of the word *like*.

*I like that* = that pleases me. This is the verb *to like.*

*What was that like?* = how was it? This uses *like* as a preposition meaning *similar to.*

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like